# How the flavor-specific variants are working?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

If you need flavor you should go to `build gradle` and add the flavors that you need

Like this

```
productFlavors {
mock {
  applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
}
prod {}
}
```

and then you need to create corresponding dir like this `/src/prod/java/`

How I thought it should work, according to build variant that was choosen for example `prodDebug` androidStudio will take as a base main source and substitute coresponding classes from dir according to choosen build variant.

But then I found this snippet which said next

> Files in the flavor-specific folders do not replace files in the main source set. Trying to do that will result in a duplicate class exception. This is a common misconception because it's how resources are merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so with basic configuration with flavors, you have two *kinds* of source sets:

1. `main` source set
2. *flavor-specific* source sets, like your `mock` and `prod`

With standard `buildTypes` configuration (*debug* and *release)*, this gives you the following **build variants** (combinations of build types and product flavors):

1. mockDebug
2. mockRelease
3. prodDebug
4. prodRelease

Each one of them uses every source set that corresponds with flavor/type name **and** the main set, so for example, the **prodRelease** will use all of the following source sets at once:

1. /src/main
2. /src/prod
3. /src/release

Effectively, the build system will 'merge' all of these into one source set, and that means if there are classes with the same path and name in these sets, a name clash occurs and compiler will fail.

The way to use source sets correctly is to omit the class that you need to be different for each set from the **main** set, but instead provide it with all the sets for each flavor / each buildType, for example:

1. *main* set has class *A.java* that references class *B.java*. B.java is omitted from main set.
2. Different *B.java* files are included in *mock* and *prod* sets (of course, don't need to be different, but need to provide the same interface, preferably with interface included in *main* set).
3. Compiler uses *B.java* from the set that is being used by the current configuration - build variant, so either the *mock* or the *prod* one.
4. Yay! Now you have two functionally different product flavors.

This behavior doesn't limit to classes, you can use flavor or type specific resources, *AndroidManifest.xml* files and just about anything that goes into the source dir.

Tip: In Android Studio you can see in the 'project files' section which files will be chosen to compile for a specific variant. To switch build variants, hit Cmd+Shift+A (mac keymap) and search for **Build Variants** phrase. It usually shows also on the left bottom side of the Android Studio window.

Answer (score 2):

The code from the `main` source set will always make it into the APK. The source files in other source sets will only be merged if the correct build variant is used. For example, you can create two files:

- src/mock/java/yourpackage/MyClass.java
- src/prod/java/yourpackage/MyClass.java

Depending on whether you're building `prod` or `mock` variant, one of those classes will be compiled and packaged with the APK. Same works for `debug` and `release`: you can have code and resources that are only packaged into debug or release versions of the app.