# Dagger2- Switching Dependencies for different flavours: Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, dagger-2, android-build-flavors

I am using Dagger 2 and would like to use it to inject different dependencies for different build flavours in Android Studio.

```
public class DemoApplication extends Application{

AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

 component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().module(new Module()).build();
    }
}


@Module
public class Module {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ClassA provideClassA(){
        return new ClassA();
    }
}



@Component (modules = {Module.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    ClassA getClassA();

}
```

Now lets say I want object of ClassA to be returned for prod flavour but an object of ClassB (which extends from ClassA) in the debug flavour.

Answer (score 2):

### Use flavor-specific source sets

For example, let's consider **mock** and **production** flavors. Create `mock` and `production` directories and put them alongside `main`, place a separate class named `Module` in both `mock` and `production` directories (the package must also be the same). This way, when you're switching build variants, the compiler will refer to either the `Module` class in `mock` or `production` flavor, allowing you to inject different implementations depending on the flavor.

Check out this reference on source sets: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

This answer might also be helpful: [How the flavor-specific variants are working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786054/how-the-flavor-specific-variants-are-working/40786283#40786283)

Comment: dagger does not seem to compile with this method

Comment: @Sunny this doesn't depend in any way on Dagger itself, only gradle is involved in the source set resolution. Make sure 1. to clean the project (to remove all previously generated dagger classes) and 2. if you have `Module` class in `mock` and `production` you cannot have a class with the same name in `main` or there will be a name clash.